# Will a Java listener wait or drop during synchronization?

Tags: java, events, synchronized

In an event listener I have:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //the same logic for mouse events, etc.
   synchronized(lockFoo) {...}
}
```

And somewhere else in the code, on a different thread:

```
public void bar() {
   synchronized(lockFoo) {...}
}
```

If *two* or more events fire while lockFoo is locked, will they FIFO cue up and wait for their turn or will they be dropped? FIFO Cuing is the more desirable behavior.

Comment: Although making Thread test cases is rarely fun, why not try it yourself then if you don't get the expected results, ask for clarification?

Comment: Off the top of my head, any thread trying to obtain the monitor lock will wait until the lock is released.  While locked, the waiting thread will enter a sleep and stop processing.  This might cause incoming events to be discard, but it will depend on the system.

Comment: @--A--C: doing so won't differentiate between "almost always" and "always".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use FIFO - then use [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) with fair constructor argument set to "true". With generic synchronization it is not possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

They will wait for their turn and eventually will be executed in unpredictable order (there is not strict FIFO).

Answer (score 0):

Threads will Queue up for sure, but the order is depending upon the `Thread Priority`, otherwise Random. There is no guaranty of a FIFO.